# Best practice package naming for multiple market releases?

Tags: android

What is recommended and/or best practice when it comes to providing an Android application on multiple markets in terms of **package naming**?

Let's say I have an app on Google Play:
**com.test.sample.pro**

Now I want this app on other markets.

1. Should I use the same package name? If no, why not?
2. What could the issues be?
3. Should I name the package always different for different markets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would keep them the same, no reason to change. Just make you sign them with the same key.

Comment: Yeah, that's kinda what I was thinking. This would make sure that my app is not installed multiple times from different markets. Thanks for your response.